# Android upload image into the server using Volley library

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to upload my captured images from camera to my 000webhost.com server using the volley library.

I want where I am getting wrong and suggest me full code solution.

I have tried to write the code, But its not working.

I am getting error as follows:

```
D/URL﹕ http:/plantnow.net16.net/uploaded.php
D/ERROR﹕ Error [com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException:
```

> "Cannot connect to server"

My PHP uploaded.php look like this. I want to s tore the images and imagepath in server.

```
<?php
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
     $image = $_POST['image'];
     require_once('dbconnect.php');
     $sql ="SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $id = 0;

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
         $id = $row['id'];
     }

     $path = "uploadedimages/$id.jpeg";
     $actualpath = "http://plantnow.net16.net/$path";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

My main activity with volley code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ProgressDialog prgDialog;
String encodedString;
String fileName;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
private Button buttonUploadPhoto;
private ImageView myimage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Set Cancelable as False
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    buttonUploadPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadPhoto);
    myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);



    buttonUploadPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            uploadImage();

        }
    });

}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

// When Image is selected from Gallery
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        String fileNameSegments[] = picturePath.split("/");
        fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];

        Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        myimage.setImageBitmap(myImg);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        myImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

        uploadImage();
    }
}



/**
 * API call for upload selected image from gallery to the server
 */
public void uploadImage() {

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http:/plantnow.net16.net/uploaded.php";
    Log.d("URL", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", response);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "The image is upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Error while loadin data!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Error [" + error + "]");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Cannot connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("image", encodedString);
            params.put("filename", fileName);

            return params;

        }

    };
    rq.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    // Dismiss the progress bar when application is closed
    if (prgDialog != null) {
        prgDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException Means http:/plantnow.net16.net couldn't convert to IP. check ur domain name or there is no connection established betwoeen your android and your server

Comment: Its connect to server. Now error is showing: "Error while loadin data!",

Comment: Remove the line "JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);" because "reponse" value is not a JSON string which must begin with { and end with }.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a typo to me.

Try to change:

```
String url = "http:/plantnow.net16.net/uploaded.php"
```

To :

```
String url = "http://plantnow.net16.net/uploaded.php"
```

Comment: Now its connect to my server but showing error: JSON Exception﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value Successfully of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.  Do I need to write any code line below  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: Error also: "Error while loadin data!",

Comment: You are responding "Successfully Uploaded"; which is not JSON String that's why.

Comment: Still I am getting D/JSON Exception﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. The above code is for uploading gallery images, I wanted to load camera captured image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below changes in your code..

```
new Response.Listener<String>()
public void onResponse(String response)
```

Replace with

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
```